# R Display by Unique Value and Frequency

Tags: r, unique, contingency

I have a dataset such as the one below except for around 5 million observations. I have already filtered the dates based on the time they were recorded in previous code to include only the calls made during working time. Now, I want to separate the dates based on WORKERCALL_ID in order to see a list of all of the unique dates for each worker and the number of times each WORKERCALL_ID shows up on each date (number of calls per date, separated by each WORKERCALL_ID. I tried to do this using a contingency matrix and then changing it to a data frame, but the file is so large that my R session always aborts. Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

```
WORKERCALL_ID     DATE
124789244   02-01-2014
128324834   05-01-2014
124184728   06-10-2014
```

An example of desired output is below, for each WORKERCALL_ID and date. My end goal is to be able to subset the result and remove the rows/ID's with a high frequency of calls.

```
WORKERCALL_ID   DATE    FREQ
124789244   02-01-2014    4
124789244   02-23-2014    1
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example using `dput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options :

```
table(df$WORKERCALL_ID, df$DATE)
```

Or, using dplyr (also including the requested added filtering out for IDs that have any cases of frequency higher than 5):

```
df %>% group_by(WORKERCALL_ID, DATE) %>% summarize(freq=n()) %>% group_by(WORKERCALL_ID) %>% 
  filter(!any(freq>5))
```

Example:

```
rbind(as.data.frame(df),data.frame(WORKERCALL_ID=128324834, DATE="Moose",freq=6,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>% group_by(WORKERCALL_ID) %>% filter(!any(freq>5))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   WORKERCALL_ID [2]
  WORKERCALL_ID DATE        freq
          <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1    124184728. 06-10-2014    1.
2    124789244. 02-01-2014    1.
```

Note how ID 128324834 is removed from the final result.

Comment: Thank you! @iod This is a long shot, but I'm trying to delete any workercall_id's from the frame that have at least one frequency over 5. Would there be any way to do this even though multiple of the same workercall_id's are still in different columns?

Comment: Sure. See my edited answer above. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I think so, but will this get rid of the ID in all rows, or just the row that is >5?

Comment: It will get rid of any row with an ID for which `any` of the rows is over 5. Why not give it a try on a sample and see for yourself?

Comment: It should get rid of them. I'm not sure what's happening with your data unless I have a concrete example. To be on the safe side (although it really shouldn't be necessary, try to insert a second `group_by` after the summarize, to make sure it's grouping the right way (see the revised code in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dplyr::count`

```
library(dplyr)
count(df,WORKERCALL_ID,DATE)
```